# ExtJS 4.1 Call One Controller From Another

Tags: events, extjs, controller

*Note: I'm a total ignoramus regarding javascript.*

I've broken my ExtJS 4.1 MVC app out into several controllers like:

```
/app/controller/Auth
    |          |Quiz
    |          |Result
    |          |Blah...
    |model/...
```

I want to respond to an "event", not a *DOM Event*, rather a `Ext.form.action.Submit.success` event by calling functions in *both* my `Auth` and `Quiz` controllers. The summarized code for the first part is here:

```
// File: app/controller/Auth.js
attemptLogin : function() {
    var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#loginpanel')[0].form;
    if (form.isValid()) {
        form.submit({
        success : function(form, action) {
            // THIS IS THE FUNCTION FROM THE CURRENT CONTROLLER
            Assessor.controller.Auth.prototype.finishLogin();
            // THIS IS THE FUNCTION FROM THE OTHER CONTROLLER
            Assessor.controller.Quiz.prototype.setupAssessment();
        },
```

This works but feels wrong. Is there a proper way to do this? It seems like I should fire a unique event that is listened to by both controllers, but I can't understand how to do that with `Ext.Event`. Any guidance?

***Thanks!** I'm really grateful for all the great ideas and advice.*

Comment: I would go with an application event bus. this is what google does for GWT. basically, listen for an event on the application. fire the event on the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It  makes sense to me to fire a custom event from the form and simply listen to it in both your controllers, like what you said here:

> It seems like I should fire a unique event that is listened to by both
>   controllers

```
// File: app/controller/Auth.js
attemptLogin : function() {
    var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.down('#loginpanel').form;
    if (form.isValid()) {
        form.submit({
        success : function(form, action) {
            // fire the event from the form panel
            form.owner.fireEvent('loginsuccess', form.owner);
        },
```

Then in each of your controllers you *can* listen to it with Controller#control, like this:

```
Ext.define('YourApp.controller.Auth', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        var me = this; 

        me.control({

            '#loginpanel': {

                loginsuccess: me.someHandler

            }
        });
    },

    someHandler: function(form) {
        //whatever needs to be done
        console.log(form);
    }
}
```

And then add the same thing to your `Quiz` controller:

```
Ext.define('YourApp.controller.Quiz', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        var me = this; 

        me.control({

            '#loginpanel': {

                loginsuccess: me.someOtherHandler

            }
        });
    },

    someOtherHandler: function(form) {
        //whatever needs to be done
        console.log(form);
    }
}
```

I've used this approach successfully in 4.1.0 and 4.1.1

Comment: We use an approach similar to this, but because we don't like some of our events being bound to a specific view, we fire our events using Ext.Viewport.fireEvent("eventname").  Then you can listen for them in any controller using the viewport reference.

Comment: @mmigdol, how do you unit-test your controllers if you fire events from Viewport?

Comment: @AlexanderTokarev, just fire events from the Viewport in the test harness...or maybe I'm misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @mmigdol, This implies that in order to test a Controller, you need to instantiate the Viewport and all its children. Or do you use some kind of test-only Viewport?

Comment: @AlexanderTokarev, that's right.  My unit tests are normally standalone apps that instantiate a single view and/or its associated controller

Answer (score 3):

It really should be

```
Assessor.controller.Auth.prototype.finishLogin.apply(this, arguments)
```

or something along these lines (in order to have a correct `this` reference that points to the 'owner' of the method, the controller object)

However, why do you use this unorthodox way to call the current controller's method. Just set the `scope` for the success callback, then call this.finishLogin().

```
form.submit({
    success : function(form, action) {
        // THIS IS THE FUNCTION FROM THE CURRENT CONTROLLER
        this.finishLogin();
        ...
    },
    scope: this
});
```

Also, you can retrieve another controller instance using `Controller#getController`.

```
this.getController('Assessor.controller.quiz').setupAssignment();
```

Then, if your controller methods are not depending on each other, you could make them both listen to the same event.

Another solution is to fire a custom event once the login is finished. You could do that on the application object

```
this.application.fireEvent('logincomplete');
```

and in your controller's init method:

```
this.application.mon('logincomplete', this.setupAssignment, this);
```

Please note that you cannot listen to those events via `Controller#control` - see Alexander Tokarev's blog post for a patch to Ext to achieve this.

Comment: You don't have to call this.application.getController(), you can just do this.getController().

Comment: I've been unable to figure out how to get the correct scope for `this`. And, all the variations of `this.getController`. `this.application` fail because, I believe, of improper scope. Since I do not understand JS well enough, I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way to fire events between controllers, but it's possible with some custom hacks. See my recent [blog post](http://nohuhu.org/development/improving-ext-js-mvc-implementation/).

Comment: It's possible: using this.getController('ControllerName').foo();

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Sure, but this way binds controllers too tight for my taste. You need to create *all* other controllers and stub them out with *all* methods you call just to test the one you're working on right now. Firing events is a lot nicer and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been looking for this and all you need is Asanda.app.getController('quiz').setupAssignment();, where Asanda is the name of your app

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Don't understand the question. If read above, this is how you call function from different controller. You need to specify where is the file. eg

Answer (score 0):

You should use a MessageBus if you have to send events between controllers:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.utils.MessageBus', {
        extend : 'Ext.util.Observable'
});
```

store the message bus in a global var

```
MsgBus = Ext.create('MyApp.utils.MessageBus');
```

Where you have to send events:

```
MsgBus.fireEvent('eventName',eventArg_1,eventArg_2);
```

Where you have to receive events:

```
MsgBus.on('eventName', functionHandler,scope); //scope is not mandatory
...
functionHandler:function(eventArg_1,eventArg_2){
...
//do whatever you want
...
}
```